# How to Parse a String in Java Script language which contains "color code change" numericals into the string such as 32m+ or 31m-

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, parsing

I'm trying to write a Firebase cloud function in java script, which sends the email notification on any new change in the Firebase remote config. On any remote config change, I do get the string in below format,

> { parameters: { [32m+ newer_value: { [39m [32m+ defaultValue: { [39m [32m+ value: "gaa_new" [39m [32m+ } [39m [32m+ } [39m } version: { [31m- versionNumber: "498" [39m [32m+ versionNumber: "499" [39m [31m- updateTime: "2021-03-09T17:57:08.755697Z" [39m [32m+ updateTime: "2021-03-09T18:01:05.485532Z" [39m } }

So I wanted to know how to get meaningful change information from the above string. (Email part is sorted to me)

Here is the string in different operations :

1. When added a new key

> { parameters: { [32m+ newer_value: { [39m [32m+ defaultValue: { [39m
> [32m+ value: "gaa_new" [39m [32m+ } [39m [32m+ } [39m } version: {
> [31m- versionNumber: "498" [39m [32m+ versionNumber: "499" [39m [31m-
> updateTime: "2021-03-09T17:57:08.755697Z" [39m [32m+ updateTime:
> "2021-03-09T18:01:05.485532Z" [39m } }

**Expected Output Message :**

A new key is added,

key name : newer_value

value : gaa_new

> { parameters: { [32m+ add_config: { [39m [32m+ defaultValue: { [39m
> [32m+ value: "test" [39m [32m+ } [39m [32m+ } [39m } version: { [31m-
> versionNumber: "500" [39m [32m+ versionNumber: "501" [39m [31m-
> updateTime: "2021-03-09T18:14:14.954691Z" [39m [32m+ updateTime:
> "2021-03-09T18:19:15.276567Z" [39m } }

**Expected Output Message :**

A new key is added,

key name : add_config

value : test

2. When remove multiple keys :

> { parameters: { [31m- dummy_value: { [39m [31m- defaultValue: { [39m
> [31m- value: "10" [39m [31m- } [39m [31m- } [39m [31m- newer_value: {
> [39m [31m- defaultValue: { [39m [31m- value: "gaa_new" [39m [31m- }
> [39m [31m- } [39m } version: { [31m- versionNumber: "499" [39m [32m+
> versionNumber: "500" [39m [31m- updateTime:
> "2021-03-09T18:01:05.485532Z" [39m [32m+ updateTime:
> "2021-03-09T18:14:14.954691Z" [39m } }

**Expected Output Message :**

few existing keys are removed,

a. key name : dummy_value

value : 10

b. key name : newer_value

value : gaa_new

3. When same key value is updated :

> { parameters: { dummy_value: { defaultValue: { [31m- value: "100000"
> [39m [32m+ value: "10" [39m } } } version: { [31m- versionNumber:
> "497" [39m [32m+ versionNumber: "498" [39m [31m- updateTime:
> "2021-03-09T17:45:47.053923Z" [39m [32m+ updateTime:
> "2021-03-09T17:57:08.755697Z" [39m } }

**Expected Output Message :**

key name : dummy_value

old value : 100000

new value : 10

```
31m+  ->   addition of something
31m-  ->   deletion of something
```

Please help me how to proceed with that, if there is any library to achieve that then also please let me know and if not then how to traverse a string and evaluate the same.

UPDATE 1 : Here I'm mentioning my theoretical approach :
When encountered "parameters" string, will look for { or {31m+ {31m- based on that would identifiy the operation as Updated, Added or deleted respectively , and the key would be identified as next string before : and after { or {32m+ or {31m- and so on.

UPDATE 2 : I used json diff without color codes as suggested by "Nina" in the comments but somehow that is not giving correct result when I am trying to send that into my email utility.

Comment: Are you you don't mean JS object? `{ parameters: {` is not valid JSON

Comment: please add your approach. and btw some valid data structures.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes it's not a valid json, it is the json diff using json-diff tool, I need to analyse the json diff string.

Comment: @NinaScholz Here is my approach theoretically ,  when I encounter "parameters" string, will look for { or {31m+ {31m-   based on that would identifiy the operation as Updated, Added or deleted respectively , and the key would be identified as next string before : and after { or {31m+ or {31m-  and so on.

Comment: please add a simple example of given structure, your diff string (if it is one ...?) and the result later.

Comment: @NinaScholz That's exactly what I did... I have given the json diff string which I get and the response which I want to make from it...

Comment: from what is the diff string?

Comment: @NinaScholz Let's say I have a JSON 1 ,, then there is some change into JSON 1 and resulting JSON is JSON2.  and the presented diff is = JSON 2 - JSON 1.          It is calculated using json-diff utility. https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff

Comment: ok. but a small example in the question would help ...? even if you take some diffs and want something with it?

Comment: @NinaScholz currently I am getting Json diff only, it will take some time me to get the sample Jsons, till that time, can you just forget it's a json diff, consider it is just a STRING and provide the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the lines with escape colors and check the signs.

```js
const
    process = string => {
        const lines = string.match(/\[3\dm.*?\[39m/g).map(s => s.slice(4, -4));
        let colon = lines[0].indexOf(':'),
            i = 0,
            key = '';

        if (lines[0][0] === '-' && lines[1][0] === '+' && lines[0].slice(1, colon) === lines[1].slice(1, colon)) {
            return [
                'UPDATE A KEY',
                `key name : ${lines[0].slice(1, colon).trim()}`,
                `old value: ${JSON.parse(lines[0].slice(colon + 1))}`,
                `new value: ${JSON.parse(lines[1].slice(colon + 1))}`
            ];
        }

        while (lines[i].slice(colon + 1).trim() === '{') {
            key += (key && '.') + lines[i].slice(1, colon).trim();
            colon = lines[++i].indexOf(':');
        }

        key += (key && '.') + lines[i].slice(1, colon).trim();

        return [
            lines[0][0] === '-' ? 'DELETE A KEY' : 'ADD A KEY',
            `key name: ${key}`,
            `value   : ${JSON.parse(lines[i].slice(colon + 1))}`,
        ];
    },
    data = [
        '{ parameters: { [32m+ newer_value: { [39m [32m+ defaultValue: { [39m [32m+ value: "gaa_new" [39m [32m+ } [39m [32m+ } [39m } version: { [31m- versionNumber: "498" [39m [32m+ versionNumber: "499" [39m [31m- updateTime: "2021-03-09T17:57:08.755697Z" [39m [32m+ updateTime: "2021-03-09T18:01:05.485532Z" [39m } }',
        '{ parameters: { [32m+ add_config: { [39m [32m+ defaultValue: { [39m [32m+ value: "test" [39m [32m+ } [39m [32m+ } [39m } version: { [31m- versionNumber: "500" [39m [32m+ versionNumber: "501" [39m [31m- updateTime: "2021-03-09T18:14:14.954691Z" [39m [32m+ updateTime: "2021-03-09T18:19:15.276567Z" [39m } }',
        '{ parameters: { [31m- dummy_value: { [39m [31m- defaultValue: { [39m [31m- value: "10" [39m [31m- } [39m [31m- } [39m [31m- newer_value: { [39m [31m- defaultValue: { [39m [31m- value: "gaa_new" [39m [31m- } [39m [31m- } [39m } version: { [31m- versionNumber: "499" [39m [32m+ versionNumber: "500" [39m [31m- updateTime: "2021-03-09T18:01:05.485532Z" [39m [32m+ updateTime: "2021-03-09T18:14:14.954691Z" [39m } }',
        '{ parameters: { dummy_value: { defaultValue: { [31m- value: "100000" [39m [32m+ value: "10" [39m } } } version: { [31m- versionNumber: "497" [39m [32m+ versionNumber: "498" [39m [31m- updateTime: "2021-03-09T17:45:47.053923Z" [39m [32m+ updateTime: "2021-03-09T17:57:08.755697Z" [39m } }'
    ];

console.log(data.map(process));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```